# What is the @ (at) symbol used for in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

Please explain what is the use of the @ (at) symbol in XSLT with an example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It represents an *attribute* in XPath. See [here](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

From the **[XPath 1.0 W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)** (fifth bullet):

> @* selects all the attributes of the
>   context node

`@*`  is a shorthand for `attribute::*`